# Wallet files are empty

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, wallet

I started `Bitcoin Core 0.20.0` and allowed it to sync with the network.

The synchronization was completed. However my balance is 0.00 and all transaction history is missing.

I tried to troubleshoot the problem. One at a time, I loaded the two wallet files (wallet.dat and default-wallet.dat) through bitcoind and checked the output.

Both these files were backuped from the last time I used Bitcoin in 2015.

Command:

```
bitcoind.exe -rescan -upgradewallet -upnp=1 -wallet=wallet.dat -datadir=.\..\BitcoinData
```

This line got me worried:

```
2020-06-10T20:19:03Z [wallet.dat] Keys: 0 plaintext, 0 encrypted, 0 w/ metadata, 0 total. Unknown wallet records: 0
```

Both wallets show this line.

Output pertaining to the wallet

```
2020-06-10T20:19:03Z [wallet.dat] Wallet File Version = 10500
2020-06-10T20:19:03Z [wallet.dat] Keys: 0 plaintext, 0 encrypted, 0 w/ metadata, 0 total. Unknown wallet records: 0
2020-06-10T20:19:03Z [wallet.dat] Performing wallet upgrade to 169900
2020-06-10T20:19:04Z [wallet.dat] External scriptPubKey Manager for output type 0 does not exist
2020-06-10T20:19:04Z [wallet.dat] External scriptPubKey Manager for output type 1 does not exist
2020-06-10T20:19:04Z [wallet.dat] External scriptPubKey Manager for output type 2 does not exist
2020-06-10T20:19:04Z [wallet.dat] Internal scriptPubKey Manager for output type 0 does not exist
2020-06-10T20:19:04Z [wallet.dat] Internal scriptPubKey Manager for output type 1 does not exist
2020-06-10T20:19:04Z [wallet.dat] Internal scriptPubKey Manager for output type 2 does not exist
2020-06-10T20:19:12Z [wallet.dat] keypool added 2000 keys (1000 internal), size=2000 (1000 internal)
2020-06-10T20:19:12Z [wallet.dat] LegacyScriptPubKeyMan::NewKeyPool rewrote keypool
2020-06-10T20:19:12Z [wallet.dat] Wallet completed loading in           10400ms
2020-06-10T20:19:12Z init message: Rescanning...
2020-06-10T20:19:12Z [wallet.dat] Rescanning last 634090 blocks (from block 0)...
2020-06-10T20:19:12Z [wallet.dat] Rescan started from block 0000000000000000000d972cc312510d2a4811854e3705a0693289d73065af75...
2020-06-10T20:19:13Z [wallet.dat] Rescan completed in             163ms
2020-06-10T20:19:13Z [wallet.dat] setKeyPool.size() = 2000
2020-06-10T20:19:13Z [wallet.dat] mapWallet.size() = 0
2020-06-10T20:19:13Z [wallet.dat] m_address_book.size() = 0
```

Should I assume the wallet keys are lost, or maybe this was a upgrade issue with the wallet. What should I try next?

Thank you.

Comment: It's probably an issue with paths. In the log before these lines, you should see a line beginning with `BerkeleyEnvironment::Open`. Odes the `LogDir` in the line have something like `<datadir>/dattabase` or `<datadir>/wallets/database` where `<datadir>` is the absolute path to your datadir?

Comment: Alternatively, instead of having the wallet files just in the datadir, put them inside folders with different names and do `-wallet=<name of folder>`. Make sure the wallet files are named `wallet.dat` within those folders.

Comment: @AndrewChow Having the `.dat` files outside the datadir was the issue. I placed them back there, now I see bitcoind has found the keys and is rescanning. I probably should have used walletdir to specify where I was storing the wallet files, instead of just issuing the command from the folder where they are in, and expect `wallet=` to do my bidding. Your hint was on track. Thank you.